# 2011 ford fusion SEL , All lights work good, Battery good, Connections good, Fuses good, won't turn over or even click, Why?

Tags: starting

Took battery out had tested, good (only yr. old w/850 CCA).. Lights are bright and do not dim when turning on key to try to start. Checked all fuses, all good. Daughter drove it to work (ran great never had any problems like this before) and 2 hrs. later went to go to break and no start, no turn over, no clicking from starter, but lights radio everything works great with the exception of the lights on floorboard and around cup holders do shut off only while key is in the starting position. They come back on as soon as key is returned to off position. The computer readout checking system on dash says everything, and I mean EVERYTHING is faulty. Damn thing will not even try to turn over. Doesn't even sound like it is even close to trying to sound like it is. After this is fixed I'm gonna find out where that Damn Ding, Ding, Ding and other chime noises it makes is coming from and ripping it out of the car... LOL!!!
So with all this said, any ideas what it might be??

Comment: What does the display indicate is wrong? Perhaps an image of the display would give a clue.

Comment: I'm heading over to car now. Unfortunately the car is across town at her work still. This started yesterday morning and I worked on it till late last night. I just got off work tonight. I'll see if I can video the dash and post it on here. I'll take pic.'s to just in case I can't figure out how to. I'm a little better with cars than I am with computers and these new phones. Might not be till tomorrow before I get to post. The display is indicating everything is faulty. Flat/low pressure tires, oil change, brake stuff, air conditioner/heat stuff, fuel, exhaust and all other categories.

Comment: Checking fuses is normally the first step when anything electrical is wrong.  a blown fuse can have some very weird symptoms.  Also, just because a battery shows over 12v and accessories work doesn't mean that it has the power to start a car.  If possible, check the battery voltage _while_ you try to start it.  If the voltage goes very low, the battery could be internally damaged.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would probably check is the voltage at the starter solenoid itself when someone is turning the key. No voltage it could be the relay. If voltage present then the solenoid is the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Change the main computer. Not everything can go wrong at once. But when car computer goes wrong it sends wrong meesages.

Comment: Honestly there's going to be a TON more troubleshooting before you "change the computer".  You don't do something like that unless you've done several tests and are absolutely sure that is the problem.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Exactly, those lights on the dashboard are lit up to prove that they work. If one or more come on when the engine is running then there is a problem,

Comment: could or can be the neutral safety switch ..hold it up in park tight while trying to turn the engine over ...if that don't work try putting it in neutral and starting